# Route-Ordering in Java-Spark, an Idea

Tags: spark-java

I sometimes get into routing problems while using Spark-Java. If i try to add mutiple routes it sometimes maskes the parameterless routes with the ones that got parameters. I diskussed the issue with a college of mine and found a solution that (i think) works quite well. Lets assume you got two routes:

```
1. /api/people/:id
2. /api/people/query
```

To make sure that both routes are available you have to register them in the right order. Which would be 2 and then 1. The reason is that spark will use the route it encouters.

We collect all our routes beforhand in a set like this:

```
private final Set<WebServerRoute> handlers = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> {
    int method = Integer.compare(o1.getMethod().ordinal(), o2.getMethod().ordinal());
    if (method != 0)
        return method;

    int indexO1 = o1.getUrl().indexOf(':');
    int indexO2 = o2.getUrl().indexOf(':');

    if (indexO1 == -1 && indexO2 == -1) {//no route parameters. Just compare by route-length
        return o2.getUrl().compareTo(o1.getUrl());
    } else if (indexO1 == -1) {//o2 route has parameter -> is greater than o1
        return -1;
    } else if (indexO2 == -1) {//o1 rout has parameter -> is greater than o1
        return 1;
    } else {//both routes got a parameter. the one with the lower index comes first
        if (indexO1 < indexO2) {//o1's parameters comes first -> o1 is bigger
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
});
```

If the Route uses a different http-method, we just take the ordinal of the method. Otherwise we search for the index of the parameter and order the routes accordingly.

The route with the **bigger** index will come first.
This way a third route like:
    3. /api/people/test/:id
would end up before Route-Nr. 1

The reason why i am bothering you with this is, comes a scenario in your mind where this poses a problem?

Best regards
Michael

Comment: Didn't you mean - the route with the **biggest** index will come first?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I will update the question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478407/spark-java-different-path-strings-map-to-same-get-method