# Spark-Java: Different Path Strings Map to Same Get Method

Tags: java, spark-java

I am running into a problem where two distinct paths are mapping to the same resource. Please let me know why the following 2 paths are mapping to the same path:

```
get("/test/:idtest/:idsimple", (request, response) -> "");
get("/test/all/:idtest", (request, response) -> "");
```

**Following two call map to the same:**

curl -X GET -i http://localhost:4567/test/2/3

curl -X GET -i http://localhost:4567/test/all/5

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for these two requests to be mapped to the first route is the order you defined them. Spark Java documentation mentions [here](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#routes) that:

> Routes are matched in the order they are defined. The first route that matches the request is invoked.

When you call `http://localhost:4567/test/2/3` Java Spark would try to match it first with the first route you defined `"/test/:idtest/:idsimple"`:

- The variable `idtest` would be matched to `2`
- The variable `idsimple` would be matched to `3`

When you call `http://localhost:4567/test/all/5` Java Spark would try to match it first with the first route you defined again:

- The variable `idtest` would be matched to `all`
- The variable `idsimple` would be matched to `5`

So both of them match and therefore mapped to this route.

If you change the order of the routes definitions, then `"/test/all/:idtest"` will be the first path to match against and then calling `http://localhost:4567/test/all/5` would be mapped to the right route, while calling `http://localhost:4567/test/2/3` would fail the first one and would be mapped to the second.

Comment: Thank you.  This does work.  I guess I need to understand routing rules to have a better idea of what is going on.  But even then the whole route ordering is not a fun thing to deal with.

Comment: Glad it works! And yeah the ordering can be a bit annoying, but if you think about it, if two requests can be mapped to the same route you have to base the decision on something, and here this something is the order.